# Why does invoking print in a subroutine append 1 to the string?

Tags: perl, printing, return-value, subroutine

I have created the following subroutine gender to randomly print string MALE or FEMALE. When subroutine is invoked, the print command suffixes a "1" at the end of the string. See the sample code and output below:

```
sub gender { 
    if ( (int rand(100)) >50) {
        print "MALE  ";
    }
    else {
        print "FEMALE";
    }
}   

foreach (1..5) {
    print &gender, "\n"; 
}
```

Notice a "1" is suffixed to "MALE" OR "FEMALE"

OUTPUT:

```
FEMALE1
FEMALE1
MALE  1
MALE  1
FEMALE1
MALE  1
```

I am using `perl v5.8.9  v5.8.9` built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

> `Binary build 826 [290470] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
>   Built May 24 2009 09:21:05`

Answer (score 14):

```
print &gender
```

calls the gender function and prints what it returns.  gender itself, as the last thing it does in either branch, prints a string.  Implicitly, it returns the result of the last expression in it (the print "MALE" or print "FEMALE"), and print, when it succeeds, returns 1.

So either do this:

```
sub gender { if ( rand(100) >= 50 ) {print "MALE  ";}  else {print "FEMALE";}}
foreach (1..5) { &gender();  print "\n"; }
```

or this:

```
sub gender { if ( rand(100) >= 50 ) {return "MALE  ";}  else {return "FEMALE";}}
foreach (1..5) { print &gender(), "\n"; }
```

Also, note that `&gender`, with & but without parentheses, is a special form of function invocation that isn't usually what people mean to use; either drop the & or add empty parentheses to your call.

I've also corrected the if test to return male 50% of the time and female 50% of the time, instead of 49% and 51% respectively.

Comment: or just drop the parentheses since the sub has been declared prior to the call. Best practice though is usually to use the empty parentheses anyway

Comment: Drop the & completely and unconditionally.  The only common case where you should ever touch & in modern Perl code is when taking a reference to a subroutine.  (There *are* other uses for it, but they are obscure.)

Comment: Ignoring  prototypes. Yay. *yawn*

Comment: If you fancy making it even more clear, ie: for explaining it for dummies,  `sub gender { return 1 }; print gender(), "\n"; `  will of course print a 1.  `if( 1 == print "hello" ) { print "printing works!" } ` demonstrates that print also returns a value, and nobody would think `print ( ( print "male" ) , "\n" )` is sensible code now do they?

Answer (score 8):

Let's get idiomatic with your code:

```
print gender(), "\n" 
    for 1..5;

sub gender {
    return  int rand(100) > 50 ? 'MALE' : 'FEMALE';
}
```

So, what did I do?

First:

1. The `gender` sub should not be called with the `&` and no parens.  This invokes the subroutine on the arguments passed to its caller.  This is handy when you have a bunch of common argument sanitizing code.  But it is not desirable or needed here.
2. I put the sub after the other code because I like to read my code from high level to specific--the opposite of how C forces you to organize things.  I don't like reading my code from the bottom up, so I did it this way.  This is purely a personal preference.  Do whatever makes you happy.  Or if you have to work with others, follow the standard you've agreed upon.
3. I shortened `foreach` to `for`.  They do exactly the same thing, one takes fewer characters.
4. I used `for` as a statement modifier.  In other words I took a simple statement `print $_, "\n";` and tacked the `for` onto the end.  For simple tasks it is nicer than using a block.  Again, this is my opinion.  Some people decry statement modifiers as *evil* and unwelcome.  If you decide to use them, keep it simple.  YMMV.
5. I got rid of the extra unneeded print *ysth* mentioned.
6. Instead of using a big if/else block, I used the ternary operator (OK, it's really just **a** ternary operator, but people call it **the** ternary operator).  It computes a test value and depending on the boolean value of the test, returns the result one of two expressions.  It is handy when you want if/else logic in an assignment.
7. 

Comment: The int doesn't really do anything practical.  It does force a small shift in the probabilities--`int(50.9)` is 50, and therefore is yields `FEMALE`.  Without the `int`, 50.9 yields `MALE`.  I guess this is an unintended feature, but I didn't want to change the probabilities.  Maybe that's what number 7 is for.

Comment: True, int() is just carried over from the work I was trying to resolve. It has no real purpose in the question under discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Without an explicit `return`, the Perl sub will return the last evaluated value.  `gender` returns a 1 because in both execution paths, it calls `print` which returns a 1.

You should either be having `gender` return a string, which the caller then `print`s, or have `gender` do the printing, and have the caller not do anything with the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everyone for helping me out with this. I found a way to make a chart I wanted. 
Here is how I finally did it;

```
print   "GENDER    NAME   AGE   HEIGHT  WEIGHT \n";
foreach (1..10) {                       ## Starting foreach loop
$age    = int(rand( 50))+10;
$height = int (rand(40)) + 50;
$weight = int (rand (100)) + 100;
sub randchar4bit {(chr int rand(25)+65).(chr int rand(25)+65). (chr int rand(25)+65).(chr int rand(25)+65)};
sub gender { return (int rand(100)>50)? "MALE    " : "FEMALE  ";} ;

print gender(), "  ", &randchar4bit,   "    $age     $height      $weight   style 1\n";
}; ## closing foreach loop
```

It generates a nice output:

```
GENDER    NAME   AGE   HEIGHT  WEIGHT
FEMALE    HHRN    41     67      165   style 1
MALE      HNMF    27     63      187   style 1
MALE      NLDB    26     54      165   style 1
FEMALE    REMB    33     71      118   style 1
MALE      TWEW    10     57      122   style 1
MALE      OCSC    35     80      168   style 1
FEMALE    TKTR    25     64      179   style 1
MALE      GMYN    47     73      123   style 1
MALE      YKUG    50     79      148   style 1
FEMALE    HDFW    47     73      159   style 1
```